# How to make check box as checked while webpage load by default in codeigniter MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

Html code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my_data"  name="my_data" value="1" <?php echo($my_data == 1 ? 'checked' : ''); ?>/>
```

Controller code:

```
$my_data_val = isset($_POST['my_data']) && $_POST['my_data'] ? "1" : "0";

$data["my_data"] = $my_data_val;
```

i want checked the check box by default while page loading.

Error result :
check box value 0 or unchecked while page loading.

Comment: how do you pass `$data` in your view?it should be like this `$this->load->view('myfile' , $data)`

Comment: echo form_checkbox('name', 'value', TRUE);//true for checked

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, pass the data as

```
$data["my_data"] = $my_data_val;
$this->load->view('myfile' , $data);
```

While in the view:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="my_data"  name="my_data" 
  value="1" <?php if($my_data==1) echo "checked='checked' "; ?>
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add follow code to your controller to pass the data

```
$data["my_data"] = $my_data_val;
$this->load->view('myfile' , $data);
```

Your view looks OK

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
echo form_checkbox('name', 'value', TRUE);//true for checked
```

put like this `if(your condition){//here}`